# on change event datepicker in Ext.form.DateField not working

Tags: extjs, datepicker

I have html span for datepicker like this

```
  <span id="spanLimitFBClaim"></span>
```

then i call it's first.js

```
$("#spanLimitPaymentDate").datepicker("LimitPaymentDate")
```

datepicker comes form another global.js

```
$.fn.datepicker = function (id) {
    var mydate = new Ext.form.DateField({
        xtype: 'datepicker',
        format: 'd-M-Y',
        margin: '2 0 2 0',
        renderTo: Ext.get($(this).attr("id")),
        cls: 'sa-datepicker',
        inputId: id,
        value: new Date()
    });
    $("#" + id).attr("readonly", true);
}
```

it is works. the problem is. i want to get change event. i try to add in global.js the listener like this

```
$.fn.datepicker = function (id) {
    var mydate = new Ext.form.DateField({
        xtype: 'datepicker',
        format: 'd-M-Y',
        margin: '2 0 2 0',
        renderTo: Ext.get($(this).attr("id")),
        cls: 'sa-datepicker',
        inputId: id,
        value: new Date(),
        listeners: {
            select: function () {
                console.log('Date selected: ', this.getValue());
            }
        }
    });
    $("#" + id).attr("readonly", true);
}
```

and it works. i see the value on global.js (console.log) the problem is how to add it in my span (from the first.js). because i do below code is not working

```
$("#spanLimitPaymentDate").datepicker("LimitPaymentDate", {
    listeners: {
        select: function () {
            console.log('Date selected: ', this.getValue());
        }
    }
});
```

i'm very newbie in ext.js, seems i was typo in using it :(

Many thanks

Comment: You want to add the change event for the datepicker in the span?

Comment: yes it is. my code is already works well, just need change event. i want to get my change value. Is it possible?

Comment: please try this once Ext.select('#LimitPaymentDate').getEl().on('select',function(picker){
    console.log('Date selected: ', picker.getValue());
});

Comment: where you are adding the above code ?Please add the piece of code how you are adding the listener .

Comment: i'm adding in my first.js  is it right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first version, you set the listener in the config of the field you create in the function.

In the second version, you set the listener as the second argument to said function, but that function only takes one argument. So the config you set there is omitted.

It should work if you change your function like this:

```
$.fn.datepicker = function (id,config) {
    var me=this;
    var mydate = new Ext.form.DateField(
        Ext.apply(config,{
            xtype: 'datepicker',
            format: 'd-M-Y',
            margin: '2 0 2 0',
            renderTo: Ext.get($(me).attr("id")),
            cls: 'sa-datepicker',
            inputId: id,
            value: new Date()
        });
    );
    $("#" + id).attr("readonly", true);
}
```

and then call

```
$("#spanLimitPaymentDate").datepicker("LimitPaymentDate", {
    listeners: {
        select: function (picker) {
            console.log('Date selected: ', picker.getValue());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You already had two parameters in your function call, but the function only took one, the other is discarded. Your first parameter, `id`, is "LimitPaymentDate", and your second parameter is the JS object `{
    listeners: {
        select: function (picker) {
            console.log('Date selected: ', picker.getValue());
        }
    }
}`. Please try to understand the basic concepts of javascript before using Ext.

Comment: sorry i'm not focus yesterday,, yes it works.. Many thanks :)